# HTML Form submitting automatically

Tags: javascript, html, sum

I am new to HTML and JavaScript. I just made a simple page to add two numbers. The output that I am getting is correct but when I click the `sum` button the sum is there for a fraction of second and then again the page reloads itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First</title>
    <script>
        function get_sum() {
            let num_a = parseInt(document.getElementById('first').value);
            let num_b = parseInt(document.getElementById('second').value);
            document.getElementById('sum').innerText = (num_a + num_b).toString(10);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return get_sum()">
    <label>First Number: <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Enter a number" required></label>
    <br>
    <label>Second Number: <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="Enter a number" required></label>
    <button type="submit">Sum </button>
</form>
<h1 id="sum"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Comment: `return false;` from the validator.

Comment: You have to `return false` from `get_sum` in order to prevent the submission.

Comment: Yeah, it works on `return false;` but what is the need of this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the `event` and add `event.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the function to prevent page from reloading since it's a `submit` button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First</title>
    <script>
        function get_sum(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let num_a = parseInt(document.getElementById('first').value);
            let num_b = parseInt(document.getElementById('second').value);
            document.getElementById('sum').innerText = (num_a + num_b).toString(10);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return get_sum(event)">
    <label>First Number: <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Enter a number" required></label>
    <br>
    <label>Second Number: <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="Enter a number" required></label>
    <button type="submit">Sum </button>
</form>
<h1 id="sum"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onsubmit` must return false to prevent browser from submitting it to server.

Like this

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="get_sum(); return false;">
```

Comment: It worked, but why do I need to give `return false;`?

Comment: Basically form is designed to be submitted to some backend code. You are not doing it and handling the form in the frontend only. The false will stop the submit from going to full loop and submitting it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to handle the click after you change the type to "button".  Or you can stop the event from propagating to the actual "submit" action.  OR, do both to prevent the submit of the form.

Why both? A form can also be submitted by hitting "return/enter" or via script.

This is perhaps a bit of overkill but shows how to handle the events.

```js
function get_sum(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let num_a = parseInt(document.getElementById('first').value);
  let num_b = parseInt(document.getElementById('second').value);
  document.getElementById('sum').innerText = (num_a + num_b).toString(10);
}
const sumButton = document.getElementById('sum-click');
sumButton.addEventListener("click", get_sum, false);

const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', get_sum);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>First Number: <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Enter a number" required></label>
  <br>
  <label>Second Number: <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="Enter a number" required></label>
  <button id="sum-values" type="submit">Sum </button>
  <button id="sum-click" type="button">Sum (Not submit)</button>
</form>
<h1 id="sum"></h1>
```